# WCF Service Reference gera arquivo vazio

Tags: .net, wcf

Estou tendo problema ao referenciar serviços WCF no Visual Studio.
Ele não gera nenhuma referência às classes do serviço a referenciar, o arquivo `Reference.vb` fica quase vazio:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.0
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
```

Vi em questões antigas no StackOverflow em inglês para desmarcar a combo "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" e realmente gera o arquivo ok. Mas além de não gostar dessa abordagem por ser um "hack", ele gera algumas referências com erros:

[image: Reference.vb com erros] erros

Ao retirar o prefixo "Global", somem os erros de compilação, mas acontecem erros de execução.

- Os Serviços estão num projeto WCF 4.0, assim como o WebSite de onde estou tentando referenciar eles.
- Se eu der "Update Service Reference" eu outras Referências atuais do projeto que estejam funcionando, acontece esse erro também.
- Estou usando Windows 8.1 e o erro ocorreu tanto no Visual Studio 2013 como 2015 CTP.

Como eu corrijo esse problema??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ocorreu porque havia uma Referência a uma DLL externa ao projeto com falha, que o Visual Studio não apontou.

Encontrei esse erro ao retirar as referências uma por uma até parar o bug.

Mais precisamente, havia uma referência ao CrystalReports.WebEngine - que embora eu não tivesse instalado o Crystal Reports Runtime para .NET, eu tinha essa Assembly possivelmente instalada pelo Windows 8.1.

Ao que parece, se o projeto não estiver 100% ok, mesmo que esteja compilando e o Visual Studio não aponte nada. Dá bug em algum processo da automatização de criação dos códigos fontes do Service Reference. Descobri que o `svcutil` estava gerando certo o código, mas seria complicando referenciar e atualizar dezenas de WCF Services manualmente.

Fica aqui o relato e o conselho para os futuros usuário que tiveram algum problema quanto a Services References: revisem suas Referências de bibliotecas do projeto.